# Justify paragraphs by changing the word-spacing

Tags: javascript, css, word-wrap, justify, word-spacing

Is there a smart way to justify paragraphs inside a fixed-width div tag without wrapping and only changing the word-spacing? See link below.

Cheers

https://jsfiddle.net/TheCoder/zhL895x9/embedded/result/

```
<style>
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 800px
}
p {
    font-size:20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#par1 {
    word-spacing: -21px;
}
#par2 {
    word-spacing: 31px;
}
#par3 {
    word-spacing: 10.5px;
}
</style>

<div>
<p id="par1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p id="par2">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
<p id="par3">Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

from

```
#par1 {
word-spacing: -21px;
}
```

to

```
#par1 {
white-space:pre-line;
}
```

Making this changes. Hope it may help

Comment: The pre-line is wrapping the paragraph... Instead i want to change the word-spacing...